# Multiple Spring application contexts using different class loaders?

Tags: spring, aspectj

Often people want to have multiple web applications share access to a single application context. How to do that is described e.g. [here](http://springtips.blogspot.com/2007/06/using-shared-parent-application-context.html).

This question is about the opposite: having multiple application contexts inside a single web application. Usually this is easy, you just create them and use them.

However there are some situations caused by static variables in Spring aspects where it becomes impossible, such as:

- You have two application contexts X and Y, both of which create a `MyBean` which has a `@Transactional` annotation
- Both X and Y contain their own transaction managers
- Both X and Y have `<tx:annotation-driven mode="aspectj"/>` declarations
- You are doing build-time AspectJ weaving

In this case the problem is that the `<tx:annotation-driven mode="aspectj"/>` is in effect converted into a bean like this:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.transaction.aspectj.AnnotationTransactionAspect"
  factory-method="aspectOf"/>
```

Note that this returns the aspect object for `AnnotationTransactionAspect`, which is a singleton stored in a static variable.  `AnnotationTransactionAspect` extends `TransactionAspectSupport`, which contains instance fields that e.g. cache the transaction manager.

The effect is that even though the beans in X and Y are totally separated, they will be fighting over the same instance fields in the `AnnotationTransactionAspect` aspect singleton. This causes e.g. "no transaction is in progress" exceptions because somebody gets the wrong transaction manager.

The same thing happens with `@Configurable`: the bean factory used to configure beans is stored in a static variable (see `AnnotationBeanConfigurerAspect.beanConfigurerSupport`). This is more of a problem, because you can avoid AspectJ with `@Transactional`, but you can't avoid it with `@Configurable`.

I can think of three solutions:

1. Stop using aspects
2. Write my own aspect
3. Create/set new context class loaders in the threads that create X and Y

Option #1 is bad because I really like `@Configurable`.

Option #2 does not look like fun.

Option #3 looks like the easy way out.

So how would option #3 work? This is where I get fuzzy. I would need the Spring classes to be loaded into different class loaders in X and Y. That means the context class loader couldn't delegate normally to it's parent (the web application class loader), etc. How would you set this up?

Thanks.

Comment: I love `@Configurable` also but maybe you should consider just not sharing the application context across web apps and instead use REST or RPC (see Finagle) for IPC across your web apps.

Comment: Although I'm still interested understanding option #3, I decided to go with option #2. See `@ThreadConfigurable` and `@ThreadTransactional` in [dellroad-stuff](http://dellroad-stuff.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/publish/reports/javadoc/index.html?org/dellroad/stuff/spring/package-summary.html)

Comment: I probably would have done that also... Maybe even add parameter for which class loader (or thread local strategy) to use on `@Thread*`. Can you post your solution (its ok to answer your own questions).

Comment: Solution is in [dellroad-stuff](http://dellroad-stuff.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/publish/reports/javadoc/index.html?org/dellroad/stuff/spring/package-summary.html) <- hyperlink

Comment: Sorry the link was next to your name and I some how missed it

Comment: I had this problem with @Configurable when tried to bring multiple instances of the same app (it was a cluster thing). I ended up loading the complete application + spring classes in a different class loader - only shared the log4j jar. I like the Thread* idea.